# Downloading package with apt-get when it's already installed on system

Tags: debian, apt-get

How to download openssh package using apt-get?

The problem is that the package is already installed so I get only:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh -d
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
openssh is already the newest version.
```

Because of being already installed, I don't get the debian package. I should remove it first, but then I would lose USB networking.

I know that this procedure is possible with aptitude, but it's not available for me.

Comment: This question should be on serverfault or superuser.

Comment: @user, is there any specific reason you want to reinstall? If you just want the .deb package for another reason, you can find it on packages.debian.org

Comment: I need to make eventually a script that fetches the package and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install openssh -d --reinstall
```

this will download the pacakge into /var/cache/apt/archives. however I think you probably mean "openssh-server" or "openssh-client" or "ssh" or something, there isn't an openssh pacakge in debian.  You also might be interested in the "--print-uris" option if you are going to be scripting this.

Comment: Thanks. In my system ssh is a meta-package containing both server and client.

Comment: Please keep in mind package are not downloaded if you have conflicts. For 1 package this is probably not the case.

Comment: A perfect answer to a tricky question! Saved my day!